# Google pagespeed- load images without affecting render time

Tags: javascript, pagespeed

I have a slider and am loading low grade images to facilitate a quick load.

on window ready i am loading the proper sized images

```
function loadImages(){

    var images= document.getElementById('dhadimages').getElementsByClassName("dhadsecondimg");
    var index;
    for (index = 0; index < images.length; ++index) {
        images[index].src= images[index].dataset.img;
    }

}

window.onload = function () { loadImages(); }
```

but pagespeed counts this as part of the render time. For the moment i am loading when the user clicks on something and obviously this works, but why is pagespeed not detecting `window.onload` and stopping measurements there? Is there any techniques beside delay or any later events to bind to?

Comment: instead of trying to cheat the timer, perform image optimizations to reduce filesize for one-off images, and where possible make sprites of collections of images and use CSS to show them in your page. that way, your page speed numbers truly reflect what a user must deal with when using your site / application

Comment: @Kristian understand what you are saying but i don't consider it cheating the timer. The images are optimized but it consists of a main picture and a number of thumbnails the user can click on to make the main picture. The smaller images wont resize to the bigger size so i need to load in higher res ones. I can do this on click but then there's a small delay on mobile devices.

Comment: you could also do special CSS image backgrounds for resolutions in some range... that way the high res image wont get loaded for small devices, and vice versa

Answer (score 0):

Add the `async` tag to your script (you may have to make this a separate script to enable you to do this).  The browser executes all of your JS before "saying" it's finished with the DOM.  Adding async as a tag to this script lets the browser continue building the DOM without waiting for the image loads.

Comment: hi mate thanks for your answer, unfortunately google pagespeed counts the loading time

Comment: It shouldn't if you do:
`< script async>
...your script...
</script>`

Comment: i agree, it shouldn't. Same as loading on onload, but google pagespeed is counting it towards pagespeed score.

Comment: do you have a web address so that I could take a look?